How to apply a shader to a game object, and not the entire canvas using Phaser
How can apply a shader to a graphics object, and not the whole canvas?
I have a wave shader example here https://phaser.io/sandbox/6SsT2zfC, and I want the wave to be unaffected by the camera's scrollX. Now, the wave looks like it's moving faster/slower when the camera moves.
Here's the main shader code
const fragShader = `
#define SHADER_NAME WATER_WAVE_FS

precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uMainSampler;
uniform float uTime;
uniform vec2 uResolution;
uniform vec2 uWaveParams; // x: amplitude, y: frequency
uniform float uSpeed;
uniform vec2 uScroll; // Camera scrollX

void main() {
    vec2 fragCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.xy);
    
    // Use fragCoord instead of fragCoord for your wave calculation
    float wave = sin(fragCoord.x * uWaveParams.y + uTime * uSpeed) * uWaveParams.x;
    
    vec2 distortedCoord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x / uResolution.x, gl_FragCoord.y / uResolution.y + wave);
    // vec2 distortedCoord = vec2((gl_FragCoord.x+uScroll.x) / uResolution.x, gl_FragCoord.y / uResolution.y + wave;
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(uMainSampler, distortedCoord);
 
    gl_FragColor = texColor;
}
`;

I tried to add a scrollX to offset the wave by passing the camera's scrollX to the shader.
For example
vec2 distortedCoord = vec2((gl_FragCoord.x+uScroll.x) / uResolution.x, gl_FragCoord.y / uResolution.y + wave;

This will only make the wave move even faster when the camera moves.
The expected result is to have the wave move consistently even when the camera is moving.
Maybe it's possible to make other adjustments to the shader based on the position of the graphics object in the scene instead?
Here are two videos. One with the camera still, and one with the camera moving.



This is odd. From a quick scan of the code, the wave should be computed purely in screen space, unless I've overlooked something. Each fragment of wave seems to be unaware of where it is in the world or how the camera is scrolling, so you should see exactly the same wave pattern whether the camera is stationary or zipping along at high speed in any direction. But that's not what you observe? Can you record a video showing the faster/slower movement?

Thanks for the comment. I've uploaded two videos now. It's also possible to try the example using the sandbox link if you want to have a closer look.

From the recordings, when the camera moves to the right, it almost looks like the wave isn't moving at all. I believe the frag-coordinates are in screen space, so when the world moves the fragment coordinates does not, but I'm not sure.

If I understand your issue correct, I assume the issue is similar to this post. you just need to add an offset to the shader.

And in your shader code the scroll uScroll variable is already prepared but not used, you would have to somehow integrate this in your shader code.

Thanks for the reference. I did try to add an offset, but it only made the wave move faster. I will give it another try to see if maybe I did something wrong

Here is  a short demo how I would add the "scroll-offset", It's not perfect, but with some tweaking you could get there. (since the wave seem they are moving it might only be an optical illusion)
You would have to:

get the pipline of the gameobject in question getPostPipeline('WaterWavePipeline')
update the "scrollValue" in the tween "onUpdate" callback.

Short Demo (based on your code):


const fragShader = `
#define SHADER_NAME WATER_WAVE_FS

precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D uMainSampler;
uniform float uTime;
uniform vec2 uResolution;
uniform vec2 uWaveParams; // x: amplitude, y: frequency
uniform float uSpeed;
uniform vec2 uScroll; // Camera scrollX

void main() {
    vec2 fragCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.xy) + uScroll ;
    
    // Use fragCoord instead of fragCoord for your wave calculation
    float wave = sin((fragCoord.x ) * uWaveParams.y + (uTime  ) * uSpeed) * (uWaveParams.x );
    
    vec2 distortedCoord = vec2((gl_FragCoord.x ) / uResolution.x, gl_FragCoord.y / uResolution.y + wave);
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(uMainSampler, distortedCoord);
 
    gl_FragColor = texColor;
    
    // Print fragCoord as color
    // l_FragColor = vec4(fragCoord, 0.0, 1.0);
}
`;

class WaterWavePipeline extends Phaser.Renderer.WebGL.Pipelines.PostFXPipeline {
  waveParams = { amplitude: 0.1, frequency: 20.0 };
  speed = .5;
  scrollX = 0;
  camera;

  constructor(game) {
    super({
      game,
      fragShader,
    });
  }

  onPreRender() {
    this.set1f('uTime', this.game.loop.time / 100);
    this.set2f('uWaveParams', this.waveParams.amplitude, this.waveParams.frequency);
    this.set1f('uSpeed', this.speed);
    this.set2f('uScroll', this.scrollX / 1000, 0); // Pass scrollX to shader
  }

  onDraw(renderTarget) {
    this.set2f('uResolution', renderTarget.width, renderTarget.height);
    this.bindAndDraw(renderTarget);
  }

  setWaveParams(amplitude, frequency) {
    this.waveParams = { amplitude, frequency };
  }

  setSpeed(speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  setScrollX(scrollX) {
    this.scrollX = scrollX;
  }

  setCamera(camera) {
    this.camera = camera;
  }
}

class Example extends Phaser.Scene
{
    create (){
        const graphics = this.add.graphics();
        graphics.lineStyle(10, 0x0000ff, 1);
        graphics.moveTo(40,90)
        graphics.lineTo(400,90)
        graphics.stroke();
        graphics.setPostPipeline('WaterWavePipeline');

        let pipe = graphics.getPostPipeline('WaterWavePipeline');
      
        // disable this tween to have a constant wave effect
        this.tweens.add({
            targets: this.cameras.main,
            scrollX: 200,
            onUpdate: () => pipe.setScrollX(this.cameras.main.scrollX),
            repeat: -1,
            duration: 5000,
            ease: 'Sine.inOut',
            yoyo: true
        });
    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.WEBGL,
    width: 500,
    height: 190,
    backgroundColor: '#ff0067',
    scene: Example,
    pipeline: { 'WaterWavePipeline': WaterWavePipeline }
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/3.87.0/phaser.min.js" ></script>




Thanks for the demo. The above is exactly what I have tried myself. It does require tweaking to get it right, but the problem arises if you have the camera move at different speeds (for example when following a player). If the camera moves faster, the wave "speed" will also be affected, which is ultimately what I want to avoid. Maybe tweaking the scrollX-factor is the only option for this kind of wave.
